# How can I speed up this MySQL Query where the WHERE clauses are already indexed?

Tags: mysql, collation, query-performance

I have the below query which takes between 300 ms and 450 ms to process.

The table has about 300k rows and is 46 MB in size.

I have the following indexes created:

1. Index1 - country and countryiso
2. Index2 - city and cityabbr
3. Index3 - city and cityabbr and country and country iso

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, timezone
FROM geolocate WHERE
(LCASE(country) = 'cambodia' OR LCASE(countryiso) = 'cambodia')
AND
(
(LCASE(city) = 'kaôh préab' OR LCASE(cityabbr) = 'kaôh préab')
);
```

300 ms I feel is too much time, but I'm not sure how to get this to speed up any more.

I've tried to create individual column indexes to no avail.

If anyone can offer any help I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Your indexes will be mostly or entirely ignored, becuase you are (presumably) indexing the value stored in the table, but doing the comparison against a mutated value (`LCASE()`). Either store the data in LCASE form, so the indexes can be used, or do an index on the computed value (I'm not sure if that's possible in MySQL).

Comment: what if you replace OR  with IN clause

Comment: Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the columns in your table use the `utf8` character set and its default collation `utf8_general_ci`:

You don't need the `LCASE()` function calls, because MySQL already uses case-insensitive comparisons. Change, for example, `LCASE(country) = 'cambodia'` to `country = 'cambodia'`.

The collation is baked into the index, so this is efficient if the indexes are present.

Your index2 is unnecessary because it's also contained in index3.

Queries with `OR` operations tend to be slow. Tricks are available to speed them up.

I can't tell whether your indexes are the right ones. For that you need to show your EXPLAIN results and your table definition.  Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance.

I would offer advice on how to alter your column definition, but you did not give us your table definition.

Comment: Thank, I'll have a look at that and update the question accordingly.

Comment: I've just removed the LCASE and most of the queries perform 10 times better, so clearly I wasn't doing something right first when I was trying this out before. Thank you.

I'll also look to get rid of the ORs.

Answer (score 0):

(O.Jones explained getting rid of `LCASE`; I will address `OR` in the context of the given query.)

Plan A:  Have your app recognize whether the names are full or abbrev.  If you are expecting the standard 2-letter country_code, such as `KH`, then check the length of the input and build the appropriate query to avoid the `OR`.  `country_code` should be `CHAR(2)` CHARACTER SET ascii`.

Plan B:  Turn `OR` into `UNION`.  With the original query, you would need 4 `SELECTs` in the `UNION`.  After Plan A, you could get away with only 2.

Plan C:  Have a lookup table with all variants of `city` -- spelled out, abbreviated, in Chinese, etc.  This table would map to the canonical spelling that is used in the main table.  With this, you avoid `OR` for `city`.

Plan D:  Have an extra `TEXT` column with city, cityabbrev, country, countryabbrev all in it.  And possibly variant spellings.  Index this column with `FULLTEXT`.  Caveat:  there are issues with short 'words'; you should probably set the min token size to 2 in order to catch the country_code.